# Invalid Authentication Token Error with Microsoft Graph for token obtained through Azure's built in app services authentication

Tags: azure-mobile-services, microsoft-graph-api

On the backend of my Azure Mobile App, I am using Azure's built in authentication services to obtain an access token when a user logs on to my app via a Microsoft account. I am successfully obtaining that token.

However, I then attempt to call out to the Microsoft Graph to obtain the authenticated user's name, email, and ID.  Azure's log stream shows me this error:

```
MicrosoftGraphServiceException: 
  Code: InvalidAuthenticationToken 
  Message: CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A
```

Here is the applicable code:

```cs
[MobileAppController]
public class MicrosoftAccountController : ApiController
{
    MicrosoftAccountCredentials credentials;

    // GET api/<controller>
    public async Task<DataObjects.User> Get()
    {

    if (credentials == null)
    {
         credentials =  
           await this.User.GetAppServiceIdentityAsync<MicrosoftAccountCredentials>(this.Request);
        var accessToken = credentials.AccessToken; 
    }


    GraphServiceClient graphClient =
    new Microsoft.Graph.GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
        new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));

    Microsoft.Graph.User graphuser = await graphClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();

}
```

Thanks for you help!

Comment: It isn't clear from your question which scopes you are requesting. Could you add an example of the JWT token you're getting back?

Comment: I'm showing this in the diagnostic log stream: 2017-11-19T22:34:03  PID[11148] Verbose     Calling into external HTTP endpoint GET https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me.

2017-11-19T22:34:04  PID[11148] Information Login completed for 'I deleted the user's email'. Provider: 'microsoftaccount'.

2017-11-19T22:34:04  PID[11148] Verbose     Writing 'AppServiceAuthSession' cookie for site 'mattsapp.azurewebsites.net'. Length: 492.

Comment: https://mattsapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/done#token=

Comment: %7B%22authenticationToken%22%3A%22eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdGFibGVfc2lkIjoic2lkOjc3YzhhZmMzOGU0NTQyOGNlNWMyNjJkNzI1NzFmOThjIiwic3ViIjoic2lkOmY0ZTNiNmZkYjQ1Y2M4NmUwMWRkNWY4ZGZiNDI3MThhIiwiaWRwIjoibWljcm9zb2Z0YWNjb3VudCIsInZlciI6IjMiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Nsb3VkZmluZGluZ3MuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9jbG91ZGZpbmRpbmdzLmF6dXJld2Vic2l0ZXMubmV0LyIsImV4cCI6MTUxMTEzNDQ0MywibmJmIjoxNTExMTMwODQ0fQ.sJiB622EGjFC6-mfQ8OfEBi0SIS4VQmCDxKHgHKZ7j8%22%2C%22user%22%3A%7B%22userId%22%3A%22sid%3Af4e3b6fdb45cc86e01dd5f8dfb42718a%22%7D%7D

Comment: This isn't a valid token for accessing Microsoft Graph. This token is for `https://cloudfindings.azurewebsites.net/`, not `https://graph.microsoft.com/` and it lacks any scopes required to call into Graph.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I assumed that you could directly access your mobile app `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount` via the browser and login with your MSA. After logged, you could try to access `https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to retrieve the logged user info as follows:

[image]

Then, you could retrieve the `access_token` and try to simulate the request via postman to narrow this issue:

[image]

> However, I then attempt to call out to the Microsoft Graph to obtain the authenticated user's name, email, and ID.

I assumed that you could call `await App.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/me", HttpMethod.Get, null);` in your mobile client after user logged to retrieve the user info. I found that you created a custom WebAPI and extracted the token based on the current request and used the graph client to retrieve the user info, I did not check your code, but you could [remote debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug) your mobile app to troubleshoot with your code.

Moreover, you could follow [App Service Token Store](https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/) for more details about App Service Authentication / Authorization.

**UPDATE:**

> However, I then attempt to call out to the Microsoft Graph to obtain the authenticated user's name, email, and ID. Azure's log stream shows me this error

I checked your code and found that Microsoft Graph targets at `graph.microsoft.com`, while the MSA login for App Service Authentication/Authorization used the [Live SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631819.aspx). And [the Live SDK](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK) is deprecated, I did not found any client SDK for consuming the Rest APIs, I assumed that you could just create the `WebRequest` and access the [Live SDK REST API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn631844.aspx) by yourself.